# Unable to remove /reconfigure external keyboard configuration in System Preferences

Tags: keyboard, macos, system-settings

The external keyboard configuration from `Preferences|Keyboard|Modifier Keys` is not working properly on my `Sierra` mac. It works fine for the same and other external/USB keyboards on my two `El Capitan` machines.

The following  http://rainer.4950.net/2009/09/30/resetting-the-usb-keyboard-type-on-mac-osx/ recommends to disconnect the external keyboard and then delete `/Library/Preferences/com.apple.keyboardtype.plist`.

However after having done so - and verified the file no longer exists:

```
$ls -l /Library/Preferences/com.apple.keyboardtype.plist
ls: /Library/Preferences/com.apple.keyboardtype.plist: No such file or directory
```

But the external keyboard still shows up:

[image]

I am trying to get back to the "Unrecognized keyboard" dialog - in the hopes of fixing key mapping problems only on this `Sierra` machine: specifically

[image]

The end goal is for the following to actually work properly: i.e. disabling caps-lock and swapping `option` and `command`.

[image]

Instead those customized settings are presently ignored and only the default mappings are actually enabled.

Comment: For some other ideas for fixing keyboard type, see http://m10lmac.blogspot.com/2009/12/fixing-keyboard-type-problems.html

Comment: It shouldn't be necessary, but have you tried [Karabiner Elements](https://github.com/tekezo/Karabiner-Elements)?

Comment: @JMY1000  Yes and I even tried Karabiner (the unsupported on Sierra one) . they both do not work.

Comment: Odd. What keyboard are you using?

Comment: This behavior occurs for the same several `ansi` USB keyboards that work fine for `El Capitan`;  a `Dell`, and two no name's

Comment: Try: (1) unplug external keyboard, (2) delete `/Library/Preferences/com.apple.keyboardtype.plist`, (3) reboot and (4) plug external keyboard.

Comment: @ignasi35 That seems like an intelligent approach. will give it a whirl later this week

Answer (score 2):

I found [ignasi35](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/333368/ignasi35)'s suggestion works as an answer to this question of how to reconfigure an external keyboard, that is:

1. Unplug external keyboard
2. Delete `/Library/Preferences/com.apple.keyboardtype.plist`
3. Reboot
4. Plug in external keyboard

In my specific situation my <kbd>`</kbd> and <kbd>§</kbd> keys were swapped and reconfiguring did put them back.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a couple of years later, but the issue remains. I just purchased a Logitech G502X gaming mouse that I hooked up to my MacBook Pro running Sonoma (14.2.1 (23C71)) and have this same issue. After installing the G Hub software, my mouse shows an inactive. I did notice that it added my mouse as a keyboard. This video on YouTube I found resolved my issue perfectly after reading through this thread: [FIX Logitech G Hub Devices Shown as Inactive on MacOS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=18ygbA-nYXE)

The key in my case was going to Input Monitoring and adding the Logitech G Hub application there. I had already made the necessary changes to the Accessibility settings.