# Test if faulty left-apple/command key on Apple Pro Keyboard

Tags: spotlight

Catalina on late-2013 iMac, newly net installed OS.
If I use keyboard viewer then if I press either right or left-<kbd>⌘</kbd> (command key) then the keys in the Keyboard panel both show outlined in Red. SO, something works with the left-<kbd>⌘</kbd> (command key)...

If I use the standard Spotlight shortcut <kbd>⌘</kbd> (command key)+space bar it ONLY works if I use the right-<kbd>⌘</kbd> (command key), nothing with the left one.

If I go to Preferences > Keyboard & Shortcuts tab I can highlight  the key sequence and creat a new one: left-<kbd>⌘</kbd> (command key)+J say, it sees and records that. If I try to change that back to left-<kbd>⌘</kbd> (command key)+space nothing happens, like no space key was pressed (Keyboard shows the cmd keys outlined but no flash for the space bar). I CAN re-define it fine with the right-<kbd>⌘</kbd> (command key).
This behaviour of no apparent Spotlight was there right from the first login after install [my habit  is left-<kbd>⌘</kbd> (command key), took ages to notice right-<kbd>⌘</kbd> (command key) worked!]

Does this make any sense? Can I fix  it? Can the command key be masking out the space bar press  somehow? (this seems to be the evidence of the Keyboard viewer test)

Comment: small footnote: the keyboard viewer app does not seem to know there is a right-control key OR a number pad and nav/right-delete section! Also it shows bright/dim icons etc whilst my keys are engraved F1 to F13. Could be an age/firmware thing?? Someone's old coffee or other physical issue?

Comment: Something is capturing that shortcut.

Comment: @marc: don't think it can be. A) this was a clean install when first noted so nothing no-standard Apple. B) if I watch keyboard and hold right-cmd and press space I see both keys highly at the right time BUT although I see left-cmd highlit it seems I can't trigger the space: I hit the space bar but the image of the space bar never highlights in red. Seems the left-cmd masks the space bar press! Maybe it is a hardware error on this not-new keyboard that I am using for the  first time. AHH - I should swap this keyboard with some other  machine  -  that could prove it  is a hardware thing.

Comment: If the keyboard viewer doesn't correctly recognise the keyboard type, try to regenerate it. Prefs/Keyboard/Keyboard/Change keyboard type… You may need to discard the old prefs first, which I'm not so sure about - maybe see https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/309036/unable-to-remove-reconfigure-external-keyboard-configuration-in-system-preferen

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I have the same issue, left-cmd key works in all cases except with cmd-space.

Comment: Never solved it, just moved some kit about and to be honest I'm not sure which keyboard (of 2 same models) it was. This keyboard right now in use MIGHT be the one. Just tried left-⌘ (command key)+space and I get Spotlight, right-⌘ (command key)+space gets Spotlight up but with § in place (or pre-pended if I had some string in there). No idea why!!! It is old and creaky but that symptom reproduces. If you find more please post info!