# Mouse Keys is enabled on '789uiojkl' and numpad

Tags: keyboard, mouse, desktop, mouse-keys

I ordered this keyboard for my Mac desktop.

https://www.amazon.ca/dp/B071ZZTNBM

As you can see, it has a numpad on the far right, just like my old one. When I enable mouse keys (I like to use the numpad to control the mouse sometimes), it works properly, but it also uses '789uiojkl' as mouse keys, which prevents me from being able to type normally. This wasn't an issue on my other keyboard. Is there any way that I can disable the '789uiojkl' mouse keys but keep the numpad ones?

From what I understand, the '789uiojkl' should only be available for keyboards that don't have mouse keys, but mine does and it enables both of them, which is beyond pointless and extremely annoying.

Comment: What was the MacOS version and "other keyboard" where you did not have the problem?   Apple's info about Mouse Keys says "Note: When Mouse Keys is on, you can’t use the keyboard or a numeric keypad to enter text."    https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/control-the-pointer-using-mouse-keys-mh27469/mac

Comment: @TomGewecke - it's definitely not 'correct' behaviour to steal *both* the numpad *and* the right-most qwerty keys. [Owner of nothing but Macs with extended keyboards since System 9.] A Boy - see if you can make it forget, then re-add - see https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/309036/85275

Comment: Just tested on a new M1 iMac, modern bluetooth magic keyboard with Touch ID, with almost no customisation [had to switch the opt-key toggle on to test. Same behaviour, mousekeys affects only the numpad, not qwerty.

Comment: @Tetsujin  I wonder if the OP's machine is Intel and if that could make a difference with that "silicon" keyboard.

Comment: @TomGewecke - not sure. The same ad does mention further down that the Touch ID version is 'for Apple Silicon'. Reqs for this one: Bluetooth-enabled Mac computer with macOS 10.12.4 or later. The Touch ID reqs: Mac with Apple silicon using macOS 11.4 or later {I have a lot of old wired ones, but only the one 'magic' on the M1 iMac, so not enough options to properly test]

Comment: Could karabiner help fix this?   https://github.com/pqrs-org/Karabiner-Elements/issues/3111